# How I can add Axis Bank payment gateway in WooCommerce website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I want to integrate payment gateway for my WooCommerce website. I have Axis bank payment gateway credentials. How I can integrate this with WooCommerce ?

I have searched lots of plugin....but I can't understand which one will be for Axis bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt any plugin gives the option to integrate a bank's payment gateway integration directly. I highly suggest using Payment Gateways like Razorpay, CCAvencue, or Instamojo for payment methods in WooCommerce. And link your Axis bank account to these services.